# WELD Exception while Migrating to Jboss EAP7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-weld

I'm facing the following exception while migrating to JBOSS EAP 7.3 from EAP 6.4.9.

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address:
>   ([("deployment" => "xxx.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080:
>   Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to
>   start service
>       Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000805: Cannot have more than one post construct method annotated
>   with @PostConstruct for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public
>   @ManagedBean class com.xxxx.xxxx.SampleManagedBean"}} ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYSRV0021:
>   Deploy of deployment "xxxx.war" was rolled back with the following
>   failure message: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxxx.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to
>   start service
>       Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000805: Cannot have more than one post construct method annotated
>   with @PostConstruct for [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public
>   @ManagedBean class com.xxxx.xxxxx.SampleManagedBean"}}

It worked well in EAP6.4.The issue is occuring in EAP 7 and above versions.
Any suggestions on this would do a great favor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your `com.xxxx.xxxx.SampleManagedBean` class, it apparently has two `@PostConstruct` methods which EAP 7.3 doesn't seem to like. I would suggest creating a new method `@PostConstruct` which will call the two current `@PostConstruct` methods from which you should remove the annotation

Comment: Do we have any other options rather than changing the code..I mean,like importing any dependency libs?

Comment: I doubt so, your JBoss EAP is correctly following specifications. I'm surprised EAP 6.4 didn't, as this constraint [isn't new](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400705/multiple-postconstruct-methods) is still true and your app runs on Spring maybe you could try desactivating WELD. That said updating your code to conform to the standards would definitely be best

Answer (score 1):

[The javadoc for `@PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) specifies that :

> Only one method can be annotated with this annotation

The error log shows us JBoss EAP 7.3 complaining that the `com.xxxx.xxxx.SampleManagedBean` class has more than one such methods. I suggest creating a new method `@PostConstruct` in this class which would call the two other methods, from which the annotation should be removed.

This is not a bug of JBoss EAP 7.3 and I doubt you can avoid fixing the class.